# Looking for example (infinitely many times differentiable)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am looking for a $C^\infty $ map $f: \textbf R^2 \longrightarrow \textbf R^2 $ where $Df(0,0)$ is singular but $f^{-1}$ exist globally and is continuous.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can take $f(x,y)=(x,y^3)$, for instance. Its inverse is $f^{-1}(x,y)=\left(x,\sqrt[3]y\right)$, which is continuous.